# Change Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I got query like this, its working as it should work but i wonder how make it in one query

```
SELECT 
(
Select count(exists)
from country c 
  join special s ON c.id_special = s.id
  join raports rap ON c.id = rap.id_raport
where c.id_document = 7 and exists = 1 
and rap.id_data = 201501 and is_id = 1
) as number_of_ID_in_table_exists,
(
 Select count(sps)
from country c 
join special s ON c.id_special = s.id
join raports rap ON c.id = rap.id_raport
where c.id_document = 7 and sps = 1 
and rap.id_data = 201501 and is_id2 = 1
 ) as number_of_ID2_in_table_exists;
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you, will have it on my mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
Select count(case when exists = 1 and is_id = 1 then 1 end) as number_of_ID_in_table_exists,
       count(case when sps = 1 and is_id2 = 1 then 1 end) as number_of_ID2_in_table_exists
from country c 
  join special s ON c.id_special = s.id
  join raports rap ON c.id = rap.id_raport
where rap.id_data = 201501 and c.id_document = 7
```

Comment: It should be exists = 1 instead of sps = 1 too, sorry my bad. Thx its work, i love you :) I tried to his something like this but i hang out :P

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN is_id  = 1 THEN 1 END) number_of_ID_in_table_exists
       SUM(CASE WHEN is_id2 = 1 THEN 1 END) number_of_ID2_in_table_exists
FROM country c 
JOIN special s ON c.id_special = s.id
JOIN raports rap ON c.id = rap.id_raport
WHERE c.id_document = 7 AND rap.id_data = 201501 AND [exists]= 1
```

Comment: It should be exists = 1 instead of sps = 1 too, sorry my bad, but its ok